# Try to view all shared files, but shows only opened before

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm developing PHP script, using Google drive API

It's work fine, but shows shared files that only opened before through google drive interface...
Same results got with 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

Why I don't see new shared files and view only Recent files?
How can I view newest files on Shared with me section?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, here's what you can do:

Share a file using `emailA` in the Drive web app to your `emailB`. Then, log your `emailB` to [Drives list explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.changes.list). The file should appear there as I've tested this myself. If it DOESN'T, the problem is not Drive API.

Either you've not properly shared the file in your code implementation or you need to re-run your PHP code.

Comment: I'm not sharing files to any account
I'm have sharable link

to add files i'm only open's shasrable link in my emailB account and them will be in Shered with me section

Comment: You said 'shared files'. I am merely demonstrating that Drives.list also returns files that are shared to you.

Comment: I'm don't have permisions to emailA account, I have only shareable link to folder in emailA account and on emailB account I want to see list of new files in  this folder... It's impossible?